# Data entry in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

l m a fresh user and l m not good at coding yet. l created a database with 3 columns: `(date, station, pcp )`.
l have `41_years_data` set and by using a `for` loop, l would like to insert these data set in database. I could not do it correctly. When l run the code, it gives

```
"c.execute("INSERT INTO pcp VALUES(kdm,station,klm)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: kdm" error.
```

l tried something but no work.

My code is below

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

conn=sqlite3.connect("pcp.db")
c=conn.cursor()

pcp=open("p.txt")

station="1"

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pcp (date DATE,stations TEXT,pcp DOUBLE)")

def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

def data_entry():
    for i in pcp:
        k=print(i)
def data_entry2():
    for a in perdelta(date(1979, 1, 1), date(2015, 1, 1), timedelta(days=1)):
        b=print(a)

def dyn():
    kdm=data_entry2()
    klm=data_entry()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO pcp(date,stations,pcp) VALUES(?,?,?)",( kdm,station,klm ))
    conn.commit()

create_table()
dyn()
```

Comment: you need to build the query and substitute the values of the variables `klm`, `kdm` and `station` into it while quoting them as strings.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO pcp VALUES(kdm,station,klm)")
```

contains the names of your variables that hold the data values.

You need to construct the `INSERT` statement by concatenating the values inside those variables. Like so. (Maybe there is a more efficient way, but I am not too familiar with python.)

```
insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO pcp(date,stations,pcp) VALUES( ' + kdm + ',' + station + ',' + klm + ')'
c.execute(insert_sql)
```

Also try to figure out query parameters instead of string concatenation, as **@colonel Thirty** has stated, you might expose yourself to SQL Injection. Think **Bobby Tables**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for correction and l corrected code but only station inserted ,date and pcp values are left as null. The code works with no error.

Comment: Use query parameters! String concatenation is vulnerable to SQL injection and there is little reason to do it.

Comment: I knew this was coming. I am not familiar with python, but yes, you are right. SQL injection would be a concern to address.

Answer (score 0):

l solved the problem and it inserted values of date, station and pcp into pcp columns but l had to use range(1000(just for trial number)) for it.is there any suggestion to make my code better?

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import *

from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

conn=sqlite3.connect("pcp.db")
c=conn.cursor()

pcp=open("p.txt")
prr=open("date.txt","w")
station="1"
date_pcp=[]
pcp_values=[]

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pcp (date DATE,stations TEXT,pcp DOUBLE)")

def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

def data_entry():
    for i in pcp:
        pcp_values.append(i)

def data_entry2():
    for a in perdelta(date(1979, 1, 1), date(2014, 7, 31), timedelta(days=1)):
        date_pcp.append(a)




def dyn():
    data_entry2()
    data_entry()
    for l in range(1000):
        kdm=date_pcp[l]
        klm=pcp_values[l]
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO pcp(date,stations,pcp) VALUES(?,?,?)""",( kdm,station,klm ))
        conn.commit()










create_table()
dyn()
```